# Converting a column from object to int in pandas and taking a count

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataset which has the dtype object but is actually integer. How do i convert it to int and take the count in that column?

```
A  B
1  2,3,45
2  3,76,455,4
3  2,22,67,78,2
```

The problem here is that this B column has dtype = object which needs to be converted to int so that I can get to know what is the count in B? I tried to using:

```
B.astype(str).astype(int)
```

but it gives me an error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,3,45'". Can somebody tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: Yes, it can be that I can add a new column C with the counts as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let `B` remain string and still get the count by counting `,` commas.

```
In [118]: df.assign(C=df.B.str.count(',').add(1))
Out[118]:
   A             B  C
0  1        2,3,45  3
1  2    3,76,455,4  4
2  3  2,22,67,78,2  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just

```
df.B.apply(lambda x :len(x.split(',')))

Out[117]: 
0    3
1    4
2    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

You can count by using regexp string character.

```
df.B.str.count('\w+')
```